# Did the British took the one of the earliest written copies of Vedas?

Tags: vedas

Max Müller was a German-born philologist and Orientalist, studied sanskrit and vedas. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_M%C3%BCller) Wikipedia article : He had to travel to London to look at documents held in the collection of the British East India Company.

Did the British took the one of the earliest written copies of Vedas?

Comment: They might have taken the copy of vedas but the oral tradition continued and vedas survived as it is, since they cannot be harmed..

Comment: Since the early copies may have been taken from us, the oral tradition does have a disadvantage that the word of mouth may change from person to person especially in this age

Comment: It is much better than destroying the copies of vedas  as other foreign invaders did